# How to override individual blogs/% page?

Tags: views

I've got a question about overriding the default blogs/username page with Views.
I've created a new view with a page display with blogs/% as path, and set arguments to user:name. I'm typing blogs/rustam, the default page of individual blog is displayed. How do I  correctly override the blog page with Views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

blogs/[username] is the path alias; the internal path is blog/[uid]. Change your view to use the internal path blog/%.

Where % represents the passed value that you are capturing like the userid. Then you will need to add an argument as well like User: User ID so that everything is consistent

Comment: Thanks for the help. But now im getting blank page at blogs/myusername. What it might be?

Comment: I think you should change the view argument to use uid instead of name.